# why aspnetboilerplate create method in RoleAppService not getting call?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

i downloaded aspnetboilerplate template from it sites and trying to work with it, template works fine when it is in development environment but when change the environment from to development to production ,role create method in RoleAppService not calling from ui but the other application service which is userappservice getting call from ui and working correctly.

things I've changed are :

1.change db to mysql so that i had to regenerate migration

2.change port in program.cs to 5050

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5050/")
            .Build();
    }
```

here is my Log.txt section that i think is important

```
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/view-resources/Views/Roles/Index.min.js  
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in 21.0463ms 404 
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/signalr/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in 17.9473ms 200 application/json
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/signalr?id=QSajncgdfPs_oDA5mHNy3g  
.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext - Completed connection handshake. Using HubProtocol 'json'.
Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub - A client is connected: {"ConnectionId":"QSajncgdfPs_oDA5mHNy3g","IpAddress":"::1","TenantId":1,"UserId":2,"ConnectTime":"1398-07-01T12:59:23.3138178+03:30","Properties":{}}
Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.AbpCommonHub - A client is registered: QSajncgdfPs_oDA5mHNy3g
soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/Roles?Name=test4&DisplayName=test4&Description=test4&permission=Pages.Users&permission=Pages.Roles  
ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Roles", area = ""}. Executing action binabtc.Web.Controllers.RolesController.Index (binabtc.Web.Mvc)
```

I double-check everything again this problem happens when switching environment to production for kestrel, as it is appear in log it could not find view-resources/Views/Roles/Index.min.js and the postback can`t get the app service url from it which is /api/services/app/Role/Create , it is weird because user appservice works fine in this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by *not call directly*?

Comment: check your server logs. you must be getting an exception.

Comment: i read from documents that app services exposed to ui directly and in template it is obvious that create method in userappservice and RoleAppService called from ui directly because there is not a create mthid in their controller.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone like me, i the problem
i didn't installed the Bundler & Minifier and view-resources/Views/Roles/Index.min.js wasn't there by default after installing the extension and minify Roles/Index.js everything worked fine